# Conflicting jars in Eclipse Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, classloader

My Eclipse project is erroring out at runtime displaying "Source not found" when reaching a line where a new instance of class `Problem` is being launched in `TopLevelDebugClass.main()`.  Please note that this happens only in Eclipse and not when I run the app in the normal console mode.

I have narrowed the problem down to two Bouncy Castle import statements which, when removed along with the code that uses them, eliminate the problem.  When I analyzed the list of dependencies brought into the project by `Maven` using [`mvn dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html), I got the following:

```
[INFO] myGroupId:myArtifactId:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- dpdncyGroupId:dpdncyArtifactId:jar:master:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.jscep:api:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
```

where `myArtifactId` corresponds to the Eclipse project I am trying to debug and where `TopLevelDebugClass` is and `dpdncyArtifactId` corresponds to another project within the same Eclipse workspace (`myArtifactId` referencing `dpdncyArtifactId`, that is).

The conflicting jars are **bcprov-jdk16/bcprov-jdk15** and **bcmail-jdk16/bcmail-jdk15**.  I verified that the 16 version set come from the dependency artifact `pom.xml` (1st node below the top level) while the 15 version set are a dependency of jscep (bottom).  Consistent with the above tree listing, the Eclipse project's Maven Dependencies are listing both sets of bcprov-jdk and bcmail-jdk, which contain many of the same classes, among which are the imports that are causing the problem (`org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest` and `org.bouncycastle.jce.X509Principal`).

I have a reason to believe that this ambiguity is causing the contention within Eclipse (but not the native JRE) as it does not know from which of the two jars to load the classes.

Is there something I can do within Eclipse to resolve this contention so that I can run my project in the debugger?  If this is a bug in Eclipse that cannot be currently worked around, any suggestion how to solve the problem within Maven would also be considered.

Last but not least, please note that I am in a new job trying to get up to speed with the environment.  Architectural change suggestions are welcome but not an answer that I am looking for as I am not yet in a position to be making such changes.  Essentially, this was architected by someone else and I am just a newcomer.

Answer (score 1):

In your dependency for `com.google.code.jscep:api`, try using an `exclusions` stanza to keep Maven from pulling in the `bcprov-jdk15` artifact. Note that this will only apply in the situation you appear to be describing, where someone foolishly distributed identically-named classes in multiple artifacts instead of versioning properly.

Comment: thanks.  how come that does not break the runtime when running out of the regular console vs Eclipse?

Comment: What doesn't "break the runtime", and what does "breaking" mean?

Comment: when I run the app standalone out of the Linux terminal vs in Eclipse

Comment: @amphibient I still have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: OK...  when I run the main class from the Linux command line, the contention does not manifest itself, i.e. the classes are loaded fine.  When i run it in Eclipse, the "Source not found" happens.  Looks like the way Eclipse works with Maven is the problem.  IOW, the problem occurs in Eclipse only and not in other modes of executions, such as the command line.

Comment: so, the bottom line being, considering that you are suggesting a fix at the Maven level and not the Eclipse level, why doesn't it also break when I run it from the command line?

Comment: @amphibient You're talking about source jars, which is only an issue for when the IDE is trying to show you the source corresponding to running bytecode. The program will *run* fine under Eclipse as long as Eclipse isn't trying to show you source code (Javadocs, whatever) at the same time. At runtime, the JVM will pick whichever version it comes across first, and unless you run into compatibility issues like using a class that's only in 1.6, you probably wouldn't notice.

Comment: but it stops and errors out even when I am not trying to step into that line of code.  essentially every time i go through there, regardless of not being interested in seeing the source code.  so i think the problem is in fundamental class loading, not just showing the source code.  also note that i am not trying to see the source of the class that is in the jar.

Comment: @amphibient Eclipse does weird things behind the scenes, and that's the only explanation I can come up with. You'd have to debug Eclipse to find out more.